# Bootstrap 4 50%-height rows/cols

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I need to make a blocks like on the picture

Left block is col-5, right is col-7, which must have two rows with 50% height of the left block.

How to make 50%-height blocks?

[image]

Comment: This can be done with Flexbox only. [Example codepen](https://codepen.io/VinayakBagaria/pen/RORwEN)

Comment: You can try using scripts by check its adjacent right panel and assign height while load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col,
.col-5,
.col-7 {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis distinctio at, molestias doloremque optio tempora laudantium facere sequi. Tempore aliquid exercitationem accusamus nulla culpa dolorum rerum consequatur impedit quia porro? Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-7">
      <div class="row h-50">
        <div class="col">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row h-50">
        <div class="col">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem....
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it this way, or use Flexbox instead of Bootstrap sizing utilities to create the layout you want. Flexbox has been designed especially to facilitate the creation of this kind of structure.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is that I set the height for a cols in the right block.

When I wrapped each .col in a .row and set a height of 50% for these rows, everything worked as it should. Like in droduit answer.